# Handling page URL hash parameters outside of Ember.js default routing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

In the page which is opened with pre-set location.hash parameters like

```
<server>/chat.html#?jid=123&friend_jid=321
```

how do I handle the params without Ember.js throwing an Error into console with manual handling of query string (no Ember routes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable the hashchange routing. You can use the:

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```

This is documented in http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/

Answer (score 0):

That was simple. Needed to do some googling before.

```
Ember.Application.create({ router: null })
```